# tag onclick being processed twice

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want clicking on an "expando" to toggle between its states: expanded and collapsed.

I'm still pretty new to DOM/JS, so my style here is probably awful; If you have any style guidelines let me know, but for right now I want to get the code working. I've tried a few different ways, like setting the expand or collapse behavior in `dom`'s `onclick` (and changing it in the `expand` and `collapse` functions), but if I do that, then for some reason clicking doesn't trigger a collapse, but it will trigger an expand.

The problem with the code below is that I can expand an expando, but when I click on it, it *also* triggers the collapse, so it expands and then immediately collapses back.

```
var expandos = document.getElementsByTagName("expando");
var uid = 0;
for(var i=0; i<expandos.length; ++i) {
    var dom = expandos[i];
    dom.id = "expando_"+uid++;

    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.src = dom.innerHTML;
    iframe.name = dom.id +".big";
    iframe.id = iframe.name;
    iframe.scrolling = "no";
    iframe.style.display = "inline";
    iframe.onclick = collapse(dom);

    var p = document.createElement("p");
    var text = document.createTextNode(dom.innerHTML);
    p.id = dom.id+".small";
    p.style.display = "inline";
    p.appendChild(text);
    p.onclick = expand(dom);

    dom.innerHTML = "";
    /*  We have to clear the innerHTML to prevent the original text from
        showing up in addition to the text added by p.
    */

    dom.appendChild(iframe);
    dom.appendChild(p);
    /*  We have to append iframe and p **after** we clear innerHTML
        because otherwise clearing innerHTML will clear the appended
        children.
    */
    function expand(dom) {
        return function() {
            alert("Expanding "+dom.id);
            var iframe = document.getElementById(dom.id+".big");
            var p = document.getElementById(dom.id+".small");
            p.style.display = "none";
            iframe.style.display = "initial";
            dom.onclick = collapse(dom);
        }
    }
    function collapse(dom) {
        return function() {
            alert("Collapsing "+dom.id);
            var iframe = document.getElementById(dom.id+".big");
            var p = document.getElementById(dom.id+".small");
            p.style.display = "initial";
            iframe.style.display = "none";
            dom.onclick = expand(dom);
        }
    }
    collapse(dom)();
}
```

The sample HTML I'm testing on:

```
<body>
<expando>The quick brown</expando> fox jumps over <expando>the lazy dog</expando>.
<script src="loadExpandos.js"></script>
</body>
```

In the same directory, I have files named "The quick brown" and "the lazy dog", and they expand properly.

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix for to get the basic functionality you want is to combine your expand and collapse into a single function and have an if/else block that checks the state. Not 100% on what caused your original issue, but I'd guess it has something to do with your onClick events not being cleared.

```
    function clickHandler(dom) {
    return function() {
        var iframe = document.getElementById(dom.id+".big");
        var p = document.getElementById(dom.id+".small");

        if(p.style.display === "initial"){
            p.style.display = "none";
            iframe.style.display = "initial";
        } else {
            p.style.display = "initial";
            iframe.style.display = "none";
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there are some flaws. With this code, the element starts with both `p` and `iframe` visible, and you can't get the onclick behavior by clicking on the iframe, even if you set both `dom.onclick = onClick(dom)` and `iframe.onclick = onClick(dom)`, so on first click, it collapses to `The Quick Brown`, and on second click, it expands to `The Expanded Quick Brown`, and then the third click onwards does nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure on the iframe behavior because they don't load with my test page, but invoking the clickHandler at the end of the for loop does prevent both the iframe and p from appearing together.